set up eclipse on windows to work with wsl
Is there a way to set up eclipse to start on windows and connect to a wsl environment?
I want something like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl for vscode
at the moment I'm using a wsl-version of eclipse (via wslg) but it's very clumky to use.
At worst is there any other ide (apart from vscode...) that offers this kind of solution?

"connect to a wsl environment" ...to solve what problem?

I am on windows and I need to develop a solution based on apache airflow, that runs only on linux. It supported wsl also (I have a debian running with the various elements) but I want to actually run the test, debug, etc from my IDE (on windows)
